# How to make revit works with an authentication enabled revit server?

Tags: revit-api, revit

My colleague likes to use Revit server in their project for project file sharing.  However, we noticed that the Revit server does not use any authentication, such that anyone who knows our Revit server address can access our project file.

So I did a little of research and found that Revit client and Revit server communicate with WCF and, as I know, WCF has an authentication mechanism. Unfortunately, I found the WCF configuration file in Revit server but not  in the Revit client.

So could anyone please tell me how to make Revit client work with an authentication-enabled revit server?

Answer (score 0):

The only approach that I'm aware of to have authentication with Revit Server is with the product called IMAGINiT Clarity Connect.
(http://www.imaginit.com/software/imaginit-utilities-other-products/clarity-connect).

(Disclosure: I work for the parent company of IMAGINiT).